# Change Element Background During Scroll

Tags: javascript

Trying to get this script to work on [this site](http://nettra.net/demo-sites/wvg/development/):

```
var t = $('#preschool-program').offset().top - 120;

    jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > t) {   
        $('body.index header').css({"background-color":"rgba(0,0,0,1)"});
    } 
    });
```

Scrolling down nearly 1/2way on the screen and the background header should turn opaque instead of staying semi-transparent. So I'm not sure why it's not working. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your script and CSS, I'm not sure where to begin...

- You're mixing `$` and `jQuery` in your code. Joomla loads jQuery in noConflict mode, so you're better off using `jQuery`
- The variable `t` cannot be set because it runs before the DOM is ready. Make sure you wait until the DOM is ready:

  ```
  jQuery(function(){ 
     var t = jQuery('#preschool-program').offset().top - 120; 
  });
  ```
- The second part should look like this:

  ```
  jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
      if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > t) {   
          jQuery('body.index header').css({"background-color":"rgba(0,0,0,1)"});
  } 
  });
  ```

  That basically works (the style is added to the header element), **but** the file `http://nettra.net/demo-sites/wvg/development/templates/wvgs/css/bootstrap.css` sets the background of the header using `background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)!important;` at about line #10983, overriding your inline style. If you remove `!important`, and make the changes above, it should work.

Comment: `so you're better off using jQuery` >> You can also use `$` as an alias which is good if you're used to using it >> `jQuery(document).scroll(function($){` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to @Johanpw's answer.

jQuery has some issues with the `!important` attribute when using `.css()` which you're going to have to use as Bootstrap is using it.

Here are 2 alternatives that you can use.

---

### Solution 1:

You can apply your styling using the `.style` function:

```
$('body.index header').attr('style', 'background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1) !important');
```

---

### Solution 2:

You could also add a class using jQuery and target this class using CSS which is much faster than applying the styling through jQuery itself.

**jQuery:**

```
$('body.index header').addClass('customBG');
```

**CSS:**

```
.customBG {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1) !important;
}
```

---

### Full code using solution 1:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  
    var t = $('#preschool-program').offset().top - 120;
  
    $(document).scroll(function () {       
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0){ 
            $('body.index header').attr('style', 'background-color: red !important');
        }       
    });
  
});
```

Comment: Isn't it the $ sign need to be replaced with 'jQuery' for better compatibility as @johanpw mentioned earlier ?

Comment: You see that I have used `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`. This means `jQuery` is the global scope which is what @johanpw mentioned to prevent conflicts, but I have used `$` as a *local* alias which will not cause conflicts as it's locked to only this scope

Comment: Yeah, I managed to replace all of the '$' with jQuery, and that seemed to have fixed it. Plus, I had another version of jQuery running (DOH!).